# Avoiding race in a sub-millisecond TOD timer

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded

Part of the project I am working on is to maintain the time-of-day, at the sub-millisecond accuracy, while not overwhelming CPU.

The controller has a pretty standard timer, with two registers, `COUNTER` and `PRELOAD`. On each system tick `COUNTER` is decremented; once it reaches 0, the timer posts an interrupt, and reloads `COUNTER` with the value from `PRELOAD`.

The value in `PRELOAD` is calculated off-line, to let the counter expire (and post the interrupt), say, every 100 milliseconds. `COUNTER` is readable at any time, which allows for a sum-millisecond precision. Yet another timer register, `STATUS`, has a `TIMER_STATUS_IF` bit, which determines the state of the timer interrupt.

The timer's registers are memory mapped. Their definitions (along with the definition of `timer`) come from the manufacturer's `#include` file. The actual address map is irrelevant.

Here is the code:

```
static volatile uint32_t ticks;

void ISR timer_isr() {
    ticks++;
    timer->STATUS &= ~TIMER_STATUS_IF;
}

uint64_t usecs() {
    uint32_t counter1 = timer->COUNTER;
    uint32_t ticks1 = ticks;
    uint32_t counter2 = timer->COUNTER;
    uint32_t ticks2 = ticks;

    if (timer->STATUS & TIMER_STATUS_IF) {
        // The interrupt has been asserted, and the counter has been reloaded,
        // but the ISR has not been run (we are called from the higher priority
        // ISR). Increment ticks manually.
        assert(ticks1 == ticks2);
        ticks2 += 1;
    } else if (counter1 > counter2) {
        // We know that between reading counters the reload did not happen.
        // Trust the first reading of ticks.
        ticks2 = ticks1;
    }
    else { // Nothing happens here. It is purely an explanation.
        // We know that between reading counters the reload did happen.
        // Trust the second reading of ticks.
    }

    return ticks2 * US_PER_TICK + (timer->PRELOAD - counter2) / CLOCKS_PER_USEC;
}
```

This works fine unless some high priority ISR takes more than 100 ms to complete. I am fine with it. If any ISR takes that long, it is much more serious design problem.

**What I don't like here.**

I am a strong advocate of a comment-less style. To quote myself, "an explanatory comment means that you fail to express the intention in the code". However, I feel I need a large explanatory comment. Any hint on how to remove it is much appreciated.

**TL;DR**

For a bit of context, the code I inherited (not for a review)

> ```
> uint64_t usecs() {
>     uint32_t counter = timer->COUNTER;
>     uint32_t ticks = ticks;
>     return ticks * US_PER_TICK + (timer->PRELOAD - counter) / CLOCKS_PER_USEC;
> }
> ```

once in a while exhibited time travel for about 100 ms into the future.

Comment: Which MCU exactly are you writing this for?

Comment: @G.Sliepen Cortex M4

Comment: That's just the CPU core, it doesn't say much about how the timer/counters work and how they are hooked up to the interrupts. Is it an STM32?

Comment: @G.Sliepen Oh, got you. It is nxp's s32k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Carefully examine all possible interactions between interrupts

There are many possible ways interrupts can happen, you should take some time and carefully try to map them out. I think you missed a few corner cases in case where `usecs()` is called from a higher priority context than `timer_isr()`. First, given your description, the function `usecs()` can be called either from a low or a high priority context:

### Low priority call to `usecs()`

It's either not called from an interrupt context, or from an interrupt with a lower priority than the timer overflow interrupt. In this context, `usecs()` might be interrupted by `timer_isr()` at any point during its execution. So look at all the possible places where the `timer_isr()` could fire:

```
// 1
uint32_t counter1 = timer->COUNTER;
// 2
uint32_t ticks1 = ticks;
// 3
uint32_t counter2 = timer->COUNTER;
// 4
uint32_t ticks2 = ticks;
// 5
```

Before I am going to look at all 5 possibilities, I'm also going to make some assumptions:

- Any higher interrupts together will never take more than 100 milliseconds. This should be reasonable, and avoids us having to worry about the timer overflowing twice while `usecs()` runs.
- The `COUNTER` effectively gets reset to `PRELOAD` by the hardware *during* the interrupt to `timer_isr()`. You must *verify* this by reading the documentation of the MCU.

So now for the five possibilities of where the timer reset happens, and after the four statements have run the results will be:

1. `ticks1 == ticks2` and `counter1 > counter2` (trivial case)
2. `ticks1 == ticks2` and `counter1 < counter2` (only counter2 is valid)
3. `ticks1 != ticks2` and `counter1 < counter2` (either ticks1+counter1 or ticks2+counter2 are valid)
4. `ticks1 != ticks2` and `counter1 > counter2` (only ticks1 is valid)
5. `ticks1 == ticks2` and `counter1 > counter2` (trivial case)

It looks like your code handles all these cases correctly.

### High priority calls to `usecs()`

Here we can never be that `timer_isr()` interrupts `usecs()`, but it could be that `usecs()` interrupted `timer_isr()`. Let's look at those cases separately.

#### `usecs()` did not interrupt `timer_isr()`

The question is now, what happens when the timer resets? Again, check the documentation of your MCU, but I am assuming that `COUNTER` will be reset to `PRELOAD`, just that `timer_isr()` doesn't fire because we are already in a higher level interrupt. So now `ticks1 == ticks2` will always be true. We still have the five positions where the reset can happen:

1. `counter1 > counter2` (ticks1 and ticks2 are behind)
2. `counter1 < counter2` (ticks2 is behind)
3. `counter1 < counter2` (ticks2 is behind)
4. `counter1 > counter2` (everything is valid)
5. `counter1 > counter2` (everything is valid)

Oops, you cannot distinguish case 1 from cases 4 and 5 just by looking at the counter values. The TIMER_STATUS_IF flag also doesn't help in distinguishing what happened, at least not if you check it *after* reading the counters. So you have to read the counter again:

```
if (timer->STATUS & TIMER_STATUS_IF) {
    // The counters wrapped somewhere prior to exactly this if-statement.
    // We assume it won't wrap again from here, because all interrupts will
    // be handled in less than 100 ms.
    counter2 = timer->COUNTER;
    ticks2 += 1;
} ...
```

#### `usecs()` did interrupt `timer_isr()`

In a way this looks simpler, because we know the counter reset just before `usecs()` was called, so we don't have to worry about the counters being able to reset during `usecs()`. However, now we have to worry about where exactly in `timer_isr()` we had the higher level interrupt. Again there are several possibilities:

```
// 1
ticks++;
// 2
timer->STATUS &= ~TIMER_STATUS_IF;
// 3
```

Oops, there is no way to distinguish case 1 from case 2 from `usecs()`! Reordering statements won't help here, there will always be a point right before and one right after the increment. The only way I see is to ensure both `ticks++` and `timer->STATUS &= ~TIMER_STATUS_IF` are executed atomically. Perhaps this can be done by having `timer_isr()` disable higher level interrupts:

```
cli(); // disable all interrupts
ticks++;
timer->STATUS &= ~TIMER_STATUS_IF;
sei(); // reenable interrupts
```

This should make `usecs()` work correctly.